# Socket blocked by pause()

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, sockets, signals

I am working on software that accepts incoming TCP connections and have come across something that I don't understand. First, I will explain what the software is basically doing. Keep in mind that some of the parts are temporary, I understand this is most likely a poor way of doing things, but during prototyping I have run across this issue.

I have the main process establish a signal handler for SIGINT. The main process then starts a new thread, call it the 'listener', with pthread_create() defaults. The listener first opens a socket, binds, listens, and sets the socket non-blocking. Then the listener will poll the socket with select(), waiting for incoming connections.

Now, if I have a dumb while(1) loop in the main thread, I am able to connect to the socket without issue. The problem is: if I replace the while(1) loop with a pause(), I can no longer connect to the socket. I know the listener thread is still active through log messages. Again, I don't plan on using the pause() but I would just like to know what is going on.

Is pause() blocking a certain signal from reaching the child thread?

**UPDATE:** The stripped down code I have provided does not seem to exhibit the same behavior. I will update again if I can determine the cause.

**UPDATE2:** I figured out the issue. There was one critical difference between the code I posted and my problem code. Here are the differences:

```
static void* listener_thread(void* arg)
{
    int listen_port = *(int *)arg;
    int listen_fd;
    fd_set readSet;
    int fdsMax, status;
    struct timeval timeout;

    if(open_listen_port(listen_port, &listen_fd) == -1)
```

...

```
int start_listener_thread(int port)
{
    int status = 0;

    if(0 > pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, listener_thread, (void *)&port))
```

And in main.c:

```
    if(0 == status && -1 == start_listener_thread(3000))
```

So you can see I was passing the port number to the thread as a pointer to a stack location. Not a good idea. The strange thing is that it would work if I changed the pause() to a while(1) loop. And with pause() the port number just happened to be a valid port.

Allocating space for the port number in start_listener_thread solves the issue. Thanks for the help along the way!

Code example (stripped down):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_t thread_id;

void sighandler(int signum)
{
}

int open_listen_port(int listenPort, int* listenFd)
{
    struct sockaddr_in listenAddr;
    int flags;

    memset(&listenAddr, 0, sizeof(listenAddr));
    listenAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    listenAddr.sin_port = htons(listenPort);
    listenAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if( (*listenFd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1 )
    {
        return(-1);
    }

    if( bind(*listenFd, (struct sockaddr*) &listenAddr,
        sizeof(listenAddr)) == -1 )
    {
        return(-1);
    }

    if( listen(*listenFd, 16) == -1 )
    {
        return(-1);
    }

    // change listener to be non-blocking
    flags = fcntl(*listenFd, F_GETFL);
    if(fcntl(*listenFd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK) == -1)
    {
        return(-1);
    }

    return (0);
}

static void* listener_thread(void* arg)
{
    int listen_fd;
    fd_set readSet;
    int fdsMax, status;
    struct timeval timeout;

    if(open_listen_port(3000, &listen_fd) == -1)
    {
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    while(1)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&readSet);
        fdsMax = 0;
        timeout.tv_sec = 0;
        timeout.tv_usec = 500000;

        FD_SET(listen_fd, &readSet);
        if(listen_fd > fdsMax)
        {
            fdsMax = listen_fd;
        }

        status = select(fdsMax + 1, &readSet, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int start_listener_thread()
{
    int status = 0;

    if(0 > pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, listener_thread, NULL))
    {
        status = -1;
    }

    return(status);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sigaction sigopt;
    int status = 0;

    memset(&sigopt, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
    sigopt.sa_handler = sighandler;
    if(0 != sigaction(SIGINT, &sigopt, NULL))
    {
        status = -1;
    }

    if(0 == status && -1 == start_listener_thread())
    {
        status = -1;
    }

    pause();

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `pause` suspends the current thread.  How about showing us a code sample?

Answer (score 2):

From `man pause` on OS X:

```
DESCRIPTION
 Pause is made obsolete by sigsuspend(2).

 The pause() function forces a process to pause until a signal is received
 from either the kill(2) function or an interval timer.  (See
 setitimer(2).)  Upon termination of a signal handler started during a
 pause(), the pause() call will return.
```

From `man pause` on Linux:

```
DESCRIPTION
 pause()  causes the calling process (or thread) to sleep until a signal
 is delivered that either terminates the process or causes  the  invoca‐
 tion of a signal-catching function.
```

Both manual pages imply that the calling *process* will sleep. Which explains not being able to call `accept()`.

Can you determine if `accept()` is being called? Are you checking all return statuses and `errno` where appropriate?

I'm not sure what the purpose of the sleeping thread is. Why not use a while loop with something like a `sleep()` call if you must keep the main thread active? (perhaps you plan to add code to poll something here later? In that case use `usleep()` with whatever interval you want to check, or `sleep(1)` if once-per-second granularity is enough?) Or just run your `select()` on the main thread.

**Edit:** It looks like the program is running to me. I modified it as follows:

```
--- /tmp/foo.c  2014-02-11 16:43:04.000000000 -0800
+++ /tmp/foo.c  2014-02-11 16:46:17.000000000 -0800
@@ -7,6 +7,7 @@
 #include <signal.h>
 #include <sys/select.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
+#include <stdio.h>

 pthread_t thread_id;

@@ -76,6 +77,7 @@
         }

         status = select(fdsMax + 1, &readSet, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
+        printf("select() woke up\n");
     }
     return NULL;
 }
```

When I make the above change, it prints `select() woke up` every half second, until I connect to the socket. Then it repeatedly prints it.

Can you better characterize the behavior you see? Is there a call that blocks, such as a read or write to the socket?

Can you attach (or run inside) `gdb` and find out what each thread is doing?

Comment: I know that accept is being called in the child thread because it is logging status messages. If the select() call returned an error status it would be logged. There is no purpose to the sleeping thread at the moment. I am just curious as to what is happening, as I mentioned already.

Comment: @jdepth for what it's worth, when I compile your example code on OS X and Linux, I can connect to the socket in both cases... that said, I don't know if I can do reads and writes. So maybe the manual pages are incorrect, and `pause()` really only does pause the current thread. Can you be more specific about the exact behavior?

Comment: For some reason the stripped down code version I provided does not exhibit the issue. I am also able to connect. I will keep investigating.

Answer (score 0):

The following program shows that a thread continues to run while the main thread is paused.  Combined with [Mike's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21716058/63743) inability to reproduce your problem on two separate platforms, I think it is fair to ask you to reconfirm that you are really seeing what you described above.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define exitOnErr(msg) do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

static void handler(int sig)
{
    printf("don't use printf in a signal handler\n");
}

void *athread(void* x)
{
    while (1)
    {
        printf("thread running\n");
        sleep(1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n", getpid());

    pthread_t pid;

    if (signal(SIGINT, handler) == SIG_ERR)
        exitOnErr("signal");

    if(pthread_create(&pid, NULL, athread, NULL) != 0)
        exitOnErr("pthread_create");

    while(1)
    {
        pause();
        printf("pause returned\n");
    }
}
```

kill -SIGINT  "pid" and kill -SIGTERM "pid" were employed.

Comment: The code I provided is actually not exhibiting the behavior I described. I took the code directly from the problem code and stripped out non-essential parts. I will go back to the problem code and see if I can determine why it is behaving differently.